# vim textwidth stops working during editing session

Tags: vim, text-width

I've searched the web and stackoverflow and have not seen any mention of this issue. Specifically, when I am editing a text file (insert mode), at some point during the editing session, textwidth stops working and my lines no longer wrap. In every instance, I am entering text at the end of the line when textwidth stops working. The only way to restore textwidth functionality is to close and reopen the file.

Has anyone else experienced this? If so, is there a fix?

Comment: Does it happen for all types of files or is it always a particular type?

Comment: What does `:verbose set tw?` (including the question mark) say after it stops working?

Comment: @JasonDown, it only happens with txt files.

Comment: @Steve, gq always works, even after wrapping stops working.